# link_to blog path from blog_id in Post table

Tags: ruby-on-rails, link-to

On my index page, I'm listing all the posts from all the blogs. How would I link_to from a post that has a blog_id to that actual blog.

I could easily in a controller do @blog = Blog.find(@posts.blog_id) if it were just one blog, but since it's not and I already have the blog_id for the post blog, I feel there has to be a way to do something like:

```
<% @posts.each do |f| %>
   <%= f.title %>
    #<%= link_to "Blog", go to the Blog using f.blog_id somehow? %>
<% end %>
```

Comment: Yes, you need to use the show action path with` link_to`, that is pretty easy. What is wrong ?

Comment: `link_to 'Blog', blog_bath(f.blog_id)` should do the trick assuming that all of the stuff you missed in your question are done in a standard way.

Comment: @BroiSatse perfect! Exactly what I was looking for.

Answer (score 0):

The answer was given in a comment from "BroiStatse" and I thought I'd give the answer to it since he answered it in the comments section.

Basically had to do this simple line:

```
link_to 'Blog', blog_path(f.blog_id)
```